# A Binomial coefficient sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

If 'n' is a positive integer and $C_k=^nC_k$, then find the value of:
$[\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{k^3}{n(n+1)^2.(n+2)}(\frac{C_k}{C_{k-1}})^2]^{-1}$

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have reduced the expression to:

$[\frac{1.n+2.(n-1)^2+3.(n-2)^3+.......+n}{n(n+1)^2.(n+2)}]^{-1}$ which I think is correct. How to proceed now?
Given asnwer is 12

Comment: What, if any, is the relationship between $k$ and $r$?

Comment: That was by mistake. There is no $r$. I have made the edit,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials and simplify:
$$\eqalign{k^3\Bigl(\frac{C_k}{C_{k-1}}\Bigr)^2
  &=k^3\Bigl(\frac{n!}{k!\,(n-k)!}\frac{(k-1)!\,(n-k+1)!}{n!}\Bigr)^2\cr
  &=k^3\Bigl(\frac{n-k+1}{k}\Bigr)^2\cr
  &=k(n+1-k)^2\cr
  &=(n+1)^2k-2(n+1)k^2+k^3\ .\cr}$$
Now using standard formulae for sums of powers,
$$\eqalign{\sum_{k=1}^n k^3\Bigl(\frac{C_k}{C_{k-1}}\Bigr)^2
  &=(n+1)^2\frac{n(n+1)}2-2(n+1)\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4\cr
  &=\frac{n(n+1)^2}{12}(6(n+1)-4(2n+1)+3n)\cr
  &=\frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{12}\cr}$$
and the rest is easy.